# How to remove non UTF-8 characters from Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow up this this question

[Removing Non ASCII characters and replacing with spaces from Pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340627/removing-non-ascii-characters-and-replacing-with-spaces-from-pandas-data-frame)

Which tells how to remove non ASCII characters from Pandas columns

```
 df['DB_user'] = df["DB_user"].apply(lambda x: ''.join([" " if ord(i) < 32 or ord(i) > 126 else i for i in x]))
```

From the UTF-8 wikipedia, UTF-8 is

> The first 128 characters of Unicode

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

So my guess is that the solution would be

```
 df['DB_user'] = df["DB_user"].apply(lambda x: ''.join([" " if ord(i) > 127 else i for i in x]))
```

Comment: Try using the str methods instead: `df["DB_user"].str.encode('utf-8', 'ignore').str.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: Also, you're probably misunderstanding what the wikipedia article says. The reason for mentioning the first 128 characters of unicode is to make the point that "valid ASCII text is valid UTF-8-encoded Unicode as well.". Utf-8 supports much much more than 128 characters.