# UnicodeDecodeError: with apply function in column for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, soundex

I have a dataframe and I want to encode each word in my column by using `soundex`, so I have to use split because `Soundex` take only the first word

then I apply this line of code but I got this error:

```
table['soundex'] = table['name'].apply(lambda x:' '.join([jellyfish.soundex(i) for i in x.split()]))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

and when I tried to apply it in other columns it works and they all same data type

my data source is a database and I have create a name column through cleansing steps
I mean it is not original from the data source.

most of the solutions with UnicodeDecodeError coming with read CSV files and in my case I do not know what causes this error

random sample of data and expected output:

```
name                       soundex
hospital food              H213 F300
good after noon            G300 A136 N500
hi                         h000
```

any help?

Comment: Please share a sample of your dataframe with expected output.

Comment: I updated the question hope it is clear

Comment: I think your data need more clean. You need to discover the row at which error occurs and modify it.

Comment: yes I did, all of the column string type, and there are no null values

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by remove non-English character using this line of code:

```
table.name=table.name.str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii')
```

reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56744855/10718214